# Add character function need to add 0 before decimal point

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following JavaScript to add a decimal into an input field:

```
function addChar(input, character) {
  if (input.value == null || input.value == "0"){
    input.value = character}
  else{
    input.value += character}
  };

$('#button-dot').click(function() {
  addChar(this.form.display, '.');
  });
```

with HTML markup:

```
<INPUT NAME="display" ID="disp" VALUE="0" SIZE="28" MAXLENGTH="25"/>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-1" VALUE="1">1</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-2" VALUE="2">2</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-3" VALUE="3">3</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-4" VALUE="4">4</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-5" VALUE="5">5</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-6" VALUE="6">6</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-7" VALUE="7">7</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-8" VALUE="8">8</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-9" VALUE="9">9</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-0" VALUE="0">0</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-dot" VALUE=".">.</button>
```

When the user presses the the `#button-dot` key prior to any number key, the decimal appears with no zero to the left of it and I would like for that to be the case. So is there a way to alter this code such that when the user inputs the decimal point as the first key, a zero will appear to the left of the decimal?

Comment: Can you share your markup too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this handler:

```
$('#button-dot').click(function(){
    var txt = disp.val().replace(/\./g, '');
    if(!txt)
        txt = '0';
    txt += '.';
    disp.val(txt);
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  var disp = $('#disp');

  //all buttons except for last button `dot`
  $('[id^=button-]').slice(0, -1).click(function() {
    var txt = disp.val();
    if('0' === txt) { //modified condition
      txt = '';
    }
    disp.val(txt + this.value);
  });

  $('#button-dot').click(function() {
    var txt = disp.val().replace(/\./g, ''); //replace all previous dots
    if (!txt)
      txt = '0';
    disp.val(txt + '.');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<INPUT NAME="display" ID="disp" VALUE="0" SIZE="28" MAXLENGTH="25" />
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-1" VALUE="1">1</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-2" VALUE="2">2</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-3" VALUE="3">3</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-4" VALUE="4">4</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-5" VALUE="5">5</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-6" VALUE="6">6</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-7" VALUE="7">7</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-8" VALUE="8">8</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-9" VALUE="9">9</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-0" VALUE="0">0</button>
<button TYPE="button" ID="button-dot" VALUE=".">.</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't work! The form requires the use of `form.display.value`

Comment: Pressing "." then a number returns the number (what should be 0.8 shows 8). Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want, but this code will replace a dot or a zero or an empty input with `0.`:

```js
function addChar(input, character) {
  if (input.value == '' || input.value == '.' || input.value == "0"){
    input.value = "0" + character}
  else{
    input.value += character}
  };

$('#button-dot').click(function() {
  addChar($('input').get(0), '.');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="i" />
<button id="button-dot">.</button>
```

Comment: @Shomz Almost works, but it adds a 0 to the left of every number key as well.

Comment: @RayonDabre, yeah, when I posted the answer, there wasn't even the HTML part included in the question, so I addressed only what OP asked for.

Comment: @newbie2015, you mean the other buttons from the HTML part you added or something in my snippet?

Comment: @Shomz The other buttons, yup.

Comment: I see, but it seems that the other answer covers everything, so no need to expand mine. :)